# Missing maven dependency using nexus setup

Tags: testing, maven-2, nexus, dependency-management

I am trying to build a maven project to test out some testing software - Arquillian.

I setup nexus and added the jboss repositories to the bottom of the public group.

When i run `mvn test` i get this error:

```
Missing:
----------
1) com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun.istack -DartifactId=istack-commons-runtime -Dversion=1.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun.istack -DartifactId=istack-commons-runtime -Dversion=1.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.jboss.arquillian.sandbox.showcase:arquillian-sandbox-showcase-jsf:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-client:pom:6.0.0.20100721-M4
        3) org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-iiop:jar:client:6.0.0.20100721-M4
        4) org.jboss.jbossts:jbossjts:jar:4.11.0.Final
        5) org.jboss.ws.native:jbossws-native-core:jar:3.3.0.CR1.SP2
        6) com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2
        7) com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.0-b01
        8) com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I checked the java.net maven 2 repository and it is definately [there](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons/).

However when i navigate to my local nexus public group, it is not there.

**How can i solve this problem? And what is the cause of this problem?** I am in way over my head with this, as I am more accustomed to using ant+ivy.

The full output from mvn is [here](http://pastie.org/1157120).

Comment: Not sure if this matters, in the ordering of my local nexus group, maven central is above java.net m2. Maven central has a org/sun/istack/ package but the istack-commons-runtime does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a bad dependency. I had to add it manually to get it all working. Terrible!

Comment: Er, it's almost a year later and now I am having this @#$%^ problem.  It hasn't been fixed yet?  Can you please say what you added manually to get it to work?  Thanks.

Comment: I had to change jaxws-rt version from 2.2 to `<version>2.2.7-promoted-b73</version>` to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

I had apparently the exact same problem.  I solved it.
In my case, the problem was that the repository that was hosting istack-common-runtime-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT was flagged "release" in the configured nexus proxy repo.  So nexus was ignoring all snapshots in that repository.
I just configured another proxy repository pointing on the same one that contains istack-common-runtime-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, but flagging it to "SNAPSHOT" when configuring it.  I then added this new proxy to my "SNAPSHOT" group.

In my settings.xml, I have a repository on the public nexus group and another on the snapshots group :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>release</id>
                <url>http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Hope this help

Comment: That solved it for me. I created another proxy repository in Nexus pointing to the same URL but with repository policy "Snapshot" and added it to the public group.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show up if you use the nexus web interface to search for it?  I've seen cases in our nexus install where an artifact looks like it's missing like this, but shows up in the search results.  If I then download it via my browser from the search results, it magically starts working at the maven command line.

Not the robust solution you want to hear, I'm sure, but it's at least worth a try.

Comment: Matt, no, it does not show up in the nexus search. A check of the local file system shows it does not exist either. Navigation via the web interface does not show it also. It's like it doesn't exist or it's read the remote repository wrong. However when i use the 'Browse Remote' for the java.net maven 2 repository, it does exist!!

Comment: I suppose I would file a bug, then.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you've added the JBoss repository to Nexus, did you remember to configure your Public Repositories group to include it?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As i mentioned in the second sentence, i have added the jboss public repository group to my local public repository group.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a corporate firewall? Perhaps a HTTP proxy needs to be configured within Nexus (See the Server admin screen)

Comment: I have configured a HTTP firewall and it has been downloading a lot of other artifacts.