# Why my maven project is not able to resolve dependency from private sonatype-nexus maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, nexus, sonatype

I have deployed a private maven repository on an aws ec2 instance. And I am able to deploy few artefacts successfully as shown.

[image: Maven Repo]

[image: Maven Repos]

My settings.xml looks like following

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://maven.tarkshala.com:10081/repository/maven-tarkshala-central/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>tarkshala</password> 
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

My project pom file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tarkshala.dhaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>UserService</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>2.1.4</dropwizard.version>
        <dropwizard.guicey.version>5.4.1</dropwizard.guicey.version>
        <dropwizard.swagger.version>2.0.16-SNAPSHOT</dropwizard.swagger.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <db.sharding.bundle.version>2.0.28-5</db.sharding.bundle.version>
        <mariadb.version>3.1.0</mariadb.version>

        <mainClass>com.tarkshala.dhaba.UserServiceApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tarkshala</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.vyarus</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-guicey</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.guicey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appform.dropwizard.sharding</groupId>
            <artifactId>db-sharding-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${db.sharding.bundle.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mariadb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tarkshala</groupId>
            <artifactId>tarkshala-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tarkshala.dhaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>userservice-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin><plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><configuration><source>9</source><target>9</target></configuration></plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java11+</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!--
                Workaround for "javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages
                defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module."
                -->
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

But as I try to build it using `mvn clean install` it fails because of not able to resolve dependency with following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.395 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-15T16:22:06+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project user-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tarkshala.dhaba:user-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.tarkshala:dropwizard-swagger:jar:2.0.16-SNAPSHOT, com.tarkshala:tarkshala-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: com.tarkshala:dropwizard-swagger:jar:2.0.16-SNAPSHOT was not found in http://maven.tarkshala.com:10081/repository/maven-tarkshala-central/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

This is happening because my artefact is present in `maven-snapshots` not in `maven-tarkshala-central`.

What should I change to resolve dependencies from both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. Basically nexus repository system has three types as following.

1. proxy, used to make a middleman repo to cache maven central repository. In this example it is `maven-tarkshala-central`
2. hosted, used to deploy our private artefacts. In this example, it is `maven-snapshots` and `maven-releases`.

My settings.xml was pointing to proxy, so it was able to resolve all external dependencies but not able to resolve private dependencies. If I make it point one of the hosted it resolves private but not central.

3. group, there is third type of repository which help to deal with the problem mentioned above. It acts as parent repository and keep proxy and hosted repos as members. So all the dependencies available in all three `maven-tarkshala-central, maven-snapshots, maven-releases` get available into this repo as shown in screenshot.

[image: group repo config]

Check the members that are available in group, mind the sequence.

Update settings.xml to use the group repo url as following

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://maven.tarkshala.com:10081/repository/maven-public/</url>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://central</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
          </repository>
        </repositories>
       <pluginRepositories>
          <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://central</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
          </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
      <!--make the profile active all the time -->
      <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>tarkshala</password> 
      </server>
    </servers>
  </settings>
```

And now happy building with `mvn clean install` :)

Answer (score 0):

> `This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced`

- Go to your local maven reposistory `~/.mvn/` and remove the `io.dropwizard` folder.
- Then build with `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: There's no need to remove the folder. The `-U` will force a reload of a) any snapshot dependency, and b) any dependency that couldn't get resolved earlier. In other words, it can perfectly be used to make Maven skip its update interval.

Comment: There are cases when `-U` doesn't work. (from personal experience)

Comment: @rgnt question is what should be done to resolve dependencies from maven-snapshots repository?